# Using HTML5 to store a database offline and update changes when the connection is restored

Tags: javascript, mysql, html, jquery-mobile

I'm just in the design stage of a new project. I'm wondering what technologies one would use to implement a small Progress (or MySQL) database that would allow browsers (on an iPad/iPhone/android or laptop etc) to download the database after they sign into the web page, then they could edit it while online or offline.

If they're online, changes could be updated immediately, but if they're offline they can modify the data locally and as soon as the connection is restored it can upload the data to the server.

- Is there a technology available in HTML5 that would allow this to occur?
- Are there limits on file size for the data that can be stored locally?

I believe the database will be small, but it may grow in some areas. Because we only need to fetch the data for that specific user, it should be quite minimal. We really want to do this as a web app to ensure cross platform compatibility, perhaps jQuery Mobile or just HTML5 and JavaScript. We would prefer not to have to develop an iOS app, Windows Form program, android app, etc.

Comment: you should just use xml in that case if the size is small.